# Error while setting up automation mobile app Testing

Tags: android, eclipse, selenium-webdriver, android-manifest, appium

Can anyone please help me out with the following error. I am unable to resolve what the issue is here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

```
[MJSONWP] Encountered internal error running command: Error: Error occured while starting App. Original error: Error executing adbExec. Original error: 'Command 'C\:\\Users\\Sehar\\android-sdks\\platform-tools\\adb.exe -P 5037 -s 0915f95176431c05 shell am start -W -n com.amazon.mShop.android.shopping/com.amazon.mShop.home.web.MShopWebGatewayActivity -S' exited with code 1'; Stderr: 'java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.amazon.mShop.android.shopping/com.amazon.mShop.home.web.MShopWebGatewayActivity launchParam=MultiScreenLaunchParams { mDisplayId=0 mFlags=0 } } from null (pid=10895, uid=2000) not exported from uid 10287
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1693)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1646)
        at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivityAndWait(ActivityManagerNative.java:3646)
        at com.android.commands.am.Am.runStart(Am.java:658)
        at com.android.commands.am.Am.onRun(Am.java:392)
        at com.android.internal.os.BaseCommand.run(BaseCommand.java:51)
        at com.android.commands.am.Am.main(Am.java:125)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.nativeFinishInit(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:301)'; Code: '1'
        at Object.wrappedLogger.errorAndThrow (C:\Users\Sehar\AppData\Local\Programs\appium-desktop\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-support\lib\logging.js:69:13)
        at ADB.callee$0$0$ (C:\Users\Sehar\AppData\Local\Programs\appium-desktop\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-adb\lib\tools\apk-utils.js:101:9)
        at tryCatch (C:\Users\Sehar\AppData\Local\Programs\appium-desktop\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\babel-runtime\regenerator\runtime.js:67:40)
        at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke [as _invoke] (C:\Users\Sehar\AppData\Local\Programs\appium-desktop\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\babel-runtime\regenerator\runtime.js:315:22)
        at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.prototype.(anonymous function) [as throw] (C:\Users\Sehar\AppData\Local\Programs\appium-desktop\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\babel-runtime\regenerator\runtime.js:100:21)
        at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke (C:\Users\Sehar\AppData\Local\Programs\appium-desktop\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\babel-runtime\regenerator\runtime.js:136:37)
        at 
    [HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 170061 ms - 1368
```

Comment: Based on your very lengthy first line of the error message, I'd say that you're attempting to access amazon.com through a web proxy that is not allowing you permission.

Comment: Yes!! so how to give permission in this case. Any explanation for that would be great thanks.

Comment: If you are using a corporate network, it's likely that your corporate network policy is preventing you from accessing certain web sites.  You'd need to take it up with your systems administrator if this is the case.